# API access &OAuth

Tags: api, google-calendar-api, shared-data

I am new to Google API usage, so please excuse the seemingly basic question.
I am writing a mobile app for members of a Club. The app needs to access a Google calendar and photo storage both maintained by the Club admin. I am having difficulty getting my head around the type of app I should be creating (Web Client, IOS, Android or all). When the OAuth consent screen opens, I am not sure which credentials the user should be entering (theirs or the Club admin).

What is required to allow the user to gain access to the shared calendar and photos?

Comment: It's  unclear for me what do you exactly mean by a club, what is your actual OAuth question? Could you maybe explain in further detail your set up?

Comment: Hi Raserhin, I am writing an app for a club of which I am a member. We have about 50 members with various mobile devices with IOS and Android operating systems.